# 2D Array where each row have diffrent type of structure's pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If we have `struct A` and its instances `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and `struct B` with instances `B1`, `B2`, `B3`

Is there a provision of having a 2D Array such that it can contain values:

```
ARRAY[][]={{&A1, &A2},{&B1, &B2}}
```

Is this approach vulnerable to errors?

Comment: You can have an array of pointers.

Comment: `ARRAY[][]` >---> `ARRAY[][2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it an array of `void *` which is valid C. But you have to keep in mind that in order to dereference a pointer the type **has to be known** at that time.

```
void * ARRAY[][]={{&A1, &A2},{&B1, &B2}};
```

is valid, but then you have to supply the type on dereferenscing

```
*(struct A *)ARRAY[0][0]
```

A probably more human readable approach would be to use pointer to union. But I would discourage both and just use two arrays.

```
union AandB {
  struct A A;
  struct B B;
};

// compiler will issue a warning if you don't typecast here
union AandB * ARRAY[][]={{(union AandB *)&A1, (union AandB *)&A2},{(union AandB *)&B1, (union AandB *)&B2}};

*ARRAY[0][0].A;
*ARRAY[1][0].B;
```